# RxJava: After Observable.just it still calls Observable.empty()

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I want to retrieve particular city from a file by its name. If the city isn't found I return Observable.empty(); Otherwise I return Observable.just(city);
Here is the code:

```
public void onAddButtonClick(String cityName) {
        Subscription subscription = repository.getCity(cityName)          
                .subscribeOn(backgroundThread)
                .flatMap(city -> repository.saveCityToDb(city))
                .observeOn(mainThread)    
                .subscribe(
                        city -> view.cityExists(),
                        throwable -> view.showCouldNotFindCity(),
                        () -> view.showCouldNotFindCity()
                );

        subscriptions.add(subscription);
    }
```

And method `getCity()`:

```
public Observable<City> getCity(String cityName){
        return Observable.defer(() -> {
            try {
                InputStream is = assetManager.open(FILE_NAME);
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();
                    if (line.toLowerCase().contains(cityName.toLowerCase())) {
                        String[] cityParams = line.split("\t");
                        City city = new City();
                        city.setId(Long.parseLong(cityParams[0]));
                        city.setName(cityParams[1]);
                        return Observable.just(city);
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                return Observable.error(e);
            }          
            return Observable.empty(); 
        });
    }
```

But the problem is when the city is found and it returns `Observable.just(city);` it goes to `return Observable.empty();` I don't know why. So the code `() -> view.showCouldNotFindCity()` is called anyway.

Comment: `view.showCouldNotFindCity()` will always be called, unless there is an error. Is this not what you want?

Comment: @Will But I want to have two options: if the city is found and if the city isn't found. And the code differs depending on the rusult. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you call this () -> view.showCouldNotFindCity() in onCompleted handler. If you take a look at the just() method in RxJava you'll see that it calls first onNext and then onCompleted methods on subscriber. So when city is found city -> view.cityExists() gets called and then immediately after () -> view.showCouldNotFindCity().

I would just throw an error if city is not found in your getCity method. Since your onError already calls desired () -> view.showCouldNotFindCity() method and remove it from onCompleted handler.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when can we use Observable.empty(); if () -> view.showCouldNotFindCity()  is called anyway? In what cases?

Comment: Usually you handle the stream of events in onNext handler and onCompleted is used for cleanup. And you can use empty when you don't push anything with onNext, instead you complete the stream immediately.